# Issues trying to connect to a remote Microsoft SQL Server with PHP using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to make a simple web application using just HTML5, CSS, Javascript, and PHP. The purpose of the app is to pull data off of a remote Microsoft SQL Server Database and put the data in a schedule table based primarily off of date.  I have most of my frameworking up, I am just having a lot of trouble trying to pull the data off of the database.  I've tried many different driver setup and I can't seem to hit anything except a brick wall.

some of the setups I've tried are :

```
    <code>
    try {
            $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$hostname; database=$dbname", $username, $pw);
           $conn->setAttribute(PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           echo"Connected Successfully";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
</code>

and

<code>
    $dsn = "sqlserver:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;charset=utf8");
       $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $pw, $opt);
    </code>
```

I am not the most versed in PHP, and I'm trying to get better. But, I've been beating my head against a wall with this one issue for almost a week now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: for anyone who comes later to try to find an answer to a question like this, I'm not sure what I did. I never ended up editing php.ini the setup that did work was

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=<IP ADDRESS>,<PORT>;Database=<DBNAME>", $username, $pw);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       echo"Connected Successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

if you are still having trouble you can use this to print out all the drivers that are installed:

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()as $driver){
          if($driver==NULL){
              echo"No PDO Drivers were found";
          }else{
              echo $driver . "<br />";
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you using Windows Authentication? And are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It's SQL Server 9.0.3042, I was just trying to use the PHP login I had set up. But, I didn't know I could use windows authentication for this.  Would it just be my login or would it differ based on who was using it? and the only error message I am getting is that the server is timing out                                     EDIT: I just started it up again today and it connected the first time it could have been some setting that didn't save. I'm honestly not sure. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: Thanks man! that worked for me too!